# docker compose starting containers out of order

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker_compose.yaml` where I want the containers to start in the following order:

1. redis
2. elasticsearch
3. myapi

```
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:7.2.4-alpine
        ports:
            - "6379"
    elasticsearch:
        container_name: es01
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    memory: 1GB
        depends_on:
            redis:
                condition: service_started
        networks:
            - elastic
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.12.0
        ports:
            - "8105:8105"
    myapi:
        container_name: myapi-service 
        build: .
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            elasticsearch:
                condition: service_started 
        ports:
            - "8000:80"

networks:
    elastic:
        driver: bridge
```

when I execute `docker compose up`, the redis service starts first as expected, but then myapi starts right after. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: `condition: service_started` isn't going to be all that useful (because "started" doesn't mean a service is actually ready to handle requests). The only way to get the sort of dependencies you want is to define health checks and then use `condition: service_healthy`.

Comment: "but then myapi starts right after" how do you know this? Logs? E.g. if logs, then perhaps `myapi` prints logs before `elasticsearch`

Comment: also as @larsks said, change `service_started` -> `service_healthy` and then add a healthcheck in `myapi` to ensure things working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how your docker compose file might look like:

```
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:7.2.4-alpine
        ports:
            - "6379"
    elasticsearch:
        container_name: es01
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    memory: 1GB
        depends_on:
            redis:
                condition: service_started
        networks:
            - elastic
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.12.0
        ports:
            - "8105:8105"
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://elasticsearch:8105"]
            interval: 10s
            retries: 5
    myapi:
        container_name: myapi-service 
        build: .
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            elasticsearch:
                condition: service_healthy 
        ports:
            - "8000:80"

networks:
    elastic:
        driver: bridge
```